# JW player controlbar isn't visible

Tags: jwplayer

I am using Jw player to stream some video using the following code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='mediaplayer/swfobject.js'></script>
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('{$movielocation}','mpl','550','470','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','{$movielocation}');
  so.addVariable('autostart','true');
  so.addVariable('controlbar','bottom');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

It works fine but the conrol bar isn't visible and I can't double click it to make it fullscreen
Any help ?

Comment: if you put your mouse on the bottom when in full screen doesn't it appear then?

Comment: I can't go to the full screen mode. Double click is not active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to go into fullscreen, you should right-click on the player and then click toggle fullscreen.

As far as the controlbar disappearing goes, it seems that you've used {$movielocation} for both the file and the location of the player.swf. Instead, your embed code should look something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','550','470','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','{$movielocation}');
  so.addVariable('autostart','true');
  so.addVariable('controlbar','bottom');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video